# Simple looking limit I am stuck on.

Tags: limits

I am stuck on the following problem

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x) \sin x}{x^2 - x}= + \infty$$
>
> Find $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: factor out $\frac{\sin(x)}x$.

Comment: Use the fact that $(\sin x) /x\to 1$ to get desired limit as $-\infty$.

Comment: Andreas, the Question emphasizes your being "stuck" on this problem with no mention of your attempt or other context, and no feedback on what your Readers wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all of the limits exist (or diverge in the appropriate sense), we have
\begin{align}
+\infty
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) \sin(x)}{x^2-x} \\
&= \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right) \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x-1} \right) \\
&= \left( \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) \right) \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x-1} \right) \tag{since $\lim_{x\to 0} \tfrac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$} \\
&= -\lim_{x\to 0} f(x). \tag{since $\lim_{x\to 0} \tfrac{1}{x-1} = -1$}
\end{align}
Therefore
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = -\infty.$$

Comment: It's almost correct, but your signs are messed up in a few places.

Comment: @zipirovich I am terribly dyslexic, and entirely willing to believe that there are sign errors.  But actually pointing out the error instead of making a cryptic and patronizing comment would be much more constructive and helpful.

Comment: And I am writing from my phone, so at the moment typing a long message is kinda challenging. I didn't mean to be patronizing, but I wanted to quickly suggest that minor errors must be fixed, as well as the final answer.

Comment: @zipirovich Gah!  Fscking found it!  $1-x \ne x-1$, though they sure look like the same thing.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Do we have to assume the existance of the limits?
Is there something wrong with this:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x(x-1)}{\sin x}=-1$.

And so,

$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x) \sin(x)}{x^2-x} * \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x(x-1)}{\sin x}=-\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = -\infty $

Comment: I'm really just assuming that $\sin(x)/x \to 1$, and $1/(x-1) \to -1$.  If I were being careful, I might have shown those limits, too.

Comment: @andreasxaralampopoulos: nothing wrong with your approach. That's the way to go. Just write $$\lim f(x) =\lim \frac{f(x) \sin x} {x^{2}-x}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x} \cdot(x-1)=\infty\cdot 1\cdot (-1)=-\infty$$ Also write your approach in question.